# oalp cube update with IIf in DMX

Tags: sql-server, analysis, olap

I need `MDX` query that will return 1\0 if the cube is up to date. Something like: case when `LAST_DATA_UPDATE > now()` then 1 else 0 end

I have the script that returns currently the 2 arguments but I cannot put them in an `IIF` statement?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT
CUBE_NAME,
 LAST_DATA_UPDATE
 --,now() as now_time
 FROM
$System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
where cube_source=1
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be MDX? A simple SSIS package will do the work for you.

Comment: BTW, will this suffice? `SELECT
'Not Processed' as CubeStatus
 FROM
$System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
where LAST_DATA_UPDATE < now() and cube_source = 1`

Comment: @yoni - your script is `sql` but you have tagged this question `mdx`?

Comment: Hi Sourav,the last script helped me - thank you!

Comment: what if the script returns NULL? can i replace it to 0?